# how to unlock rootviewcontroller header file in iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, viewcontroller

Hi Acidentally locked my rootviewcontroller.h file in my application, so if i write some code

in that file it shows "Not Writable RootViewController.h", i am a beginer so please help me how to unlock that .h file.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lock/unlock file easily by using the lock button (see below) in the text editor's navigation bar. See the [XCode Workspace Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/100-The_Text_Editor/text_editor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002679-SW3) for details.

[alt text http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/art/navigation_bar.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/art/navigation_bar.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

solution, thats small mistake,

heres a solution, this may help some beginer like me,

if u need to protect your file from editing, you can select that file , and click the lock icon, that will be appear above split window icon, in xcode,(right edge). so that u cannot make changes on that file, if u need to unlock, just click once again.

thats it,